# How to create and delete an empty file on a remote server in Java

Tags: java, php, android

How to create and delete an empty file on a remote server like http://example.com/myfolder in Java for an Android app like input.lck
Java Client side to create:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/myfolder");    
File sourceFile = new File("input.lck");
myentity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));    
httppost.setEntity(myentity);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

Server side PHP code:

```
<?php
echo $_FILES['image']['name'] . '<br/>';

$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

try {
    //throw exception if can't move the file
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        throw new Exception('Could not move file');
    }

    echo "The file " . basename($_FILES['image']['name']) .
    " has been uploaded";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('File did not upload: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Code to delete:

```
File file = new File("input.lck");
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/myfolder/input.lck");
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file);
file.delete()
```

create input.lck with HttpPut:

```
HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut("http://10.0.2.2/media/fileUpload.php");
File sourceFile = new File("input.lck");
entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));
httpPut.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPut);
HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
```

which gives FileNotFound error on PHP

Delelete input.lck with HttpDelete:

```
HttpDelete httpDelete = new HttpDelete("http://10.0.2.2/media/uploads/input.lck");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpDelete);
HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
```

which gives 405 response code

Comment: Also I need to know how to delete it.

Comment: This is a very broad question, as it would involve server code, client code, etc. Please narrow down your question. Thanks!

Comment: I want to create and delete it from client side.

Comment: Move code from comments into question.

Comment: You have the code to send. Does it work? What's the question? Your code to delete copies the file to a local directory and deletes the local copy. It doesn't delete the original. Hard to see why you ever thought would. You would have to send, and implement, an HTTP DELETE.

Comment: Since I am going to create input.lck on fly, I get fileNotFound exception: /input.lck: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory when I want to create it.

Comment: Of course. It doesn't exist. But you don't need to create a local file at all. Just send an HTTP PUT with an empty body, and react accordingly at the server end.

Comment: I added the code and error for HttpPut and HttpDelete

Comment: You need to implement PUT and DELETE at the server, as I said above. They won't just work by magic.